# .NET Directory.GetFiles() different behavior in different Windows Servers

Tags: c#, .net, getfiles

GetFiles() return all files in Windows Server 2016 (and Windows 10) but in Windows Server 2019 returns only not zero byte files.
At least i start to think that different server versions could be a source of such different behavior because there is no additional configurations for reading file for environments and no physical coded Length != 0 check anywhere so difference could be in environment itself.

Reason for question is that i can't find any documentation to prove that theory.

Comment: Maybe .net fwk user or app pool identity on Windows Server 2019 have other permissions ?  Or maybe you have another .net fwk version running on some server.

Comment: What version of .net you use?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! 
The answer itself wasn't relevant for comments but they helped!
During scouting settings found shady scheduled job which hardcoded messes with file list making it look like zero files aren't read...holly molly
Should i delete this question now?

Comment: No, you should not. Somebody can read question and comments